# Bootstrap - Want two div to be in Horizontal Direction

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put two div in columns in a single row using bootstrap code. But they are still coming vertical. I want image and text to be side by side in horizontal direction.

My code is like :-

```
<div class="tab-pane tab-content <?php if ($is_active) { echo 'active'; $is_active = false; } ;?>" id="cratsart" >
          <div class="row">
        <?php  
        $product_id =  $this->request->get['product_id'];
        $sql_cratsart = 'SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'crats_arts_involved where product_id='.$product_id.'';
        $query65_cratsart = $this->db->query($sql_cratsart);
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($query65_cratsart->rows);
        $cratsart = $query65_cratsart->rows;
        if($cratsart){
                foreach($cratsart as $cratsart_data){       
             ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <img src="https://www.wmtransfer.com/img/icons/wmlogo_128.png" alt="<?php echo $cp['alt'];?>"/>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <h4><?php echo $cratsart_data['title'];?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $cratsart_data['description'];?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The screen shot of the same is
[image]

Comment: move <div class="row"> into the loop

Comment: Have you included bootstrap css ? it should be working fine.

Comment: As @PWC said , try moving your `<div class="row">` into loop ..

Comment: @PWC - I have tried that also. But still the result is same

Comment: Is the output HTML valid? maybe end tag is missed.

Comment: @PWC I have checked the tag all are fine

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine. (p.s. add col-sm-* or col-xs-* for mobile device)

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://www.wmtransfer.com/img/icons/wmlogo_128.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur in tortor ac ex convallis gravida sit amet eget sem. Vivamus bibendum tincidunt risus ut ultrices. Mauris quis erat consequat, eleifend sapien ac, mollis quam. Aliquam odio lectus, consequat at magna id, efficitur euismod ante. Sed ac elit vitae odio tempus accumsan. Suspendisse leo ante, venenatis vel leo nec, euismod faucibus orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lectus metus, ullamcorper vehicula dui ac, posuere feugiat turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur in tortor ac ex convallis gravida sit amet eget sem. Vivamus bibendum tincidunt risus ut ultrices. Mauris quis erat consequat, eleifend sapien ac, mollis quam. Aliquam odio lectus, consequat at magna id, efficitur euismod ante. Sed ac elit vitae odio tempus accumsan. Suspendisse leo ante, venenatis vel leo nec, euismod faucibus orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://www.wmtransfer.com/img/icons/wmlogo_128.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur in tortor ac ex convallis gravida sit amet eget sem. Vivamus bibendum tincidunt risus ut ultrices. Mauris quis erat consequat, eleifend sapien ac, mollis quam. Aliquam odio lectus, consequat at magna id, efficitur euismod ante. Sed ac elit vitae odio tempus accumsan. Suspendisse leo ante, venenatis vel leo nec, euismod faucibus orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lectus metus, ullamcorper vehicula dui ac, posuere feugiat turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur in tortor ac ex convallis gravida sit amet eget sem. Vivamus bibendum tincidunt risus ut ultrices. Mauris quis erat consequat, eleifend sapien ac, mollis quam. Aliquam odio lectus, consequat at magna id, efficitur euismod ante. Sed ac elit vitae odio tempus accumsan. Suspendisse leo ante, venenatis vel leo nec, euismod faucibus orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```